# Lua String replace

Tags: string, replace, lua, gsub, lua-patterns

How would i do this?

I got this:

```
name = "^aH^ai"
string.gsub(name, "^a", "")
```

which should return "Hi", but it grabs the caret character as a pattern character

What would be a work around for this? (must be done in gsub)

Comment: Because ^ is a special character, you need use % to escape it in Lua.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Try:

```
name = "^aH^ai"
name = name:gsub("%^a", "")
```

See also: http://lua-users.org/wiki/StringLibraryTutorial

Comment: The tutorial uses a slightly different syntax. Why is `gsub` written with a `:` instead of a `.` in this answer?

Comment: @AndersonGreen: it can be called as a library function of the `string` library or as a method on a `string` object. The `:` is syntax sugar in Lua which effectively implies the object on which the method is called being passed as first parameter.

Comment: What if we want to replace special characters with special character? like email = email:gsub("%+", "%2b"). Effectively we want to to URL Encode the + to %2b